# Rails 3: organize controllers code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controllers, code-organization

In my ROR application i have many controllers organized by namespace like this.
[image: application controllers]

now, in `Telemetry/data_controller.rb` i have got a core method (here is used for polling data from [memcached](http://www.memcached.org)) that i should also use in `ecc/controlcentres_controller.rb`. 
For DRY reason i wanna put this method somewhere i can call it from both controllers, but not in all my application. 
I have considered the following issues that do not seem correct:

- move it in `application_controller.rb` for logistical reasons (only `ecc` and `telemetry` need this method and put it in `application_controller.rb` means to put it in each controllers)
- move it in `lib` folder cause it's a core method
- turn it in an helper method, cause does not fall within the parameters of [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html/)

any suggestion?

Comment: what about a concern?

Comment: Ok i have documented about concern. But i can use it in Rails 3.2.13 without any problems?

Comment: its just including a module, yes

Comment: Like i suspect. I'll try thanks!

Comment: if i put `include ConcernModule` in my controller Rails raise `AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'get' could not be found for Telemetry::DataController`. `ConcernModule` code is only `module ConcernModule extend ActiveSupport::Concern end`